# Calling the same function multiple times in select

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I have the a function and I want to see its return value using different parameters side by side. For example the output should be:

```
div04 div05 ...
 10    13   ...
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
Select 
    Top10_fn_getMeasure006('04', '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31') as Div04
    Top10_fn_getMeasure006('05', '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31') as Div05
```

I am getting a syntax error and cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the error say? Where is it putting the pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate the items on your "select" list by a comma:

```
Select 
    Top10_fn_getMeasure006('04', '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31') as Div04
,   Top10_fn_getMeasure006('05', '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31') as Div05
```